# The third dual can be "decomposed" with the dual and his annihilator

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

My teacher says that is an easy exercise to see that $X^{***}= X^* \bigoplus J(X)^\bot$. That is, $X^*$ is complemented in $X^{***}$ and $J(X)^\bot$ is the topological complement. 
Here $J$ is the canonical James map $J:X\to X^{**}$.
( I've already read other similar questions on this forum, but they did not help me )

Comment: You mean that $J$ is the canonical map $X\to X^{**}$?

Comment: @egreg I believe so, I edited the question to that effect, because I believe that is what is being asked.

Answer (score 2):

Note that we should be careful with technicalities. For the statement to make strict sense we actually want to prove that, for the canonical embedding $J_*: X^* \rightarrow X^{***}$, $J_*(X^*)$ is complemented in $X^{***}$.

Let us consider the map $\Phi:X^{***}\to X^{***}$ defined by $\Phi=J_*\circ J^*$. Here $J^*$ is the adjoint of $J$. It is a simple exercise to prove that $\Phi$ is a projection onto $J_*(X^*)$, that is, $\Phi$ is continuous and $\Phi^2 = \Phi$. We thus have $X^{***}=X^*\oplus_A(1-\Phi)X^{***}$ (Technically here we are identifying $X^*$ with $J_*(X^*)$). Here subscript $A$ denotes the algebraic direct sum, because we do not yet know that this is a topological complement. (If you know that a continuous projection gives rise to a topological complement with this decomposition then you actually do, but you do not need this knowledge for this proof.)

However, if we can show that $J(X)^\perp=(1-\Phi)X^{***}$ we will be done, because we know that the annihilator of a subspace is closed. Now $f\in(1-\Phi)X^{***}$ if and only if $f=g-\Phi g$ for some $g\in X^{***}$. We note that $\Phi g$ is the functional $\Phi_g$ satisfying $\Phi_g x=g(x)$ for all $x\in J(X).$ Thus if $x\in J(X)$ we have $f(x)=g(x)-\Phi_g x=0$. Conversely, if $h\in X^{***}$ is such that $h(x)=0$ for all $x\in J(X)$, we can write $h=h-\Phi h$. Thus $J(X)^\perp=(1-\Phi)X^{***}$ and we are done.

Comment: Since $\Phi$ is a continuous projection, doesn't that automatically imply that $X^{***}=X^*\oplus(1-\Phi)X^{***}$ in the Banach space sense? Since both $Im \, \Phi = \{x \vert \Phi x = x\} , \; Ker \, \Phi = (1 - \Phi)X^{***}$ are closed.

Comment: @pitariver Yes a continuous projection does imply the existence of a topological complement, but I wasn't sure whether the OP would know that, and because we had to prove that $(1-\Phi)X^{***}$ was an annihilator anyway this way seemed the most efficient.